# Get multiple unchecked value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to create a list of items dynamically using jQuery and each item should have checkbox along with it to its extreme right with property checked.
We should have a option to uncheck those checkbox. At the end a button should be there which take the values of the list items which were unchecked.

Firstly, I am unable to see the output. Secondly, If a solution is there for my requirement please do help.And if possible please explain a bit since i m very new to programming. Below is my code.

```
<div class="ps_server"></div>
```

```js
PrimaryValues = { 
    "EUTESTAPP01": "EUTESTAPP01", 
    "EUTESTAPP02": "EUTESTAPP02"
};

$.each(PrimaryValues, function(key, value) {
    $(".ps_server").append($("<li></li>").attr("value", key).text(value));
    var $check = $("li[value=" + key + "]").append($("<input/>").attr({
        type: 'checkbox',
        name: 'check',
        value: 'None',
        id: 'slideOne'             
    }).prop('checked', true).css('float', 'right'));
    var $combine = $check.append($(<label>").attr('for', 'slideOne').css('float', 'right'));
});
$(".ps_server").append($("<a>Get Details</a>").attr({
    class: 'btn btn-info',
    href: "#",
    role: "button"
}));
});
```

I want the checkbox to have a look like this
[Unable to css property using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266995/unable-to-css-property-using-jquery/38267721#38267721)

Comment: Your `label` element is missing an opening quote

Comment: Even after correcting that its not coming :(